# Problems with LKM loading data from Oracle 12c to SQL Database on Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, etl, oracle12c, oracle-data-integrator

I try to create Loading Knowledge Modules (LKM) which transfers data (about 2 - 3 million rows) from the table located on Oracle (Source Service) to MS SQL Database on Azure (Staging Area). So I can't use for instance LKM SQL to AZURE, because it's too slow.

In the manual I found information that the best solution is used:

> **5.1.3.3 Loading Using Unload/Load**
>
> When the source result set is on a remote database server, an alternate solution to using the agent to
> transfer the data is to unload it to a file and then load that file
> into the staging area. This is usually the most efficient method when
> dealing with large volumes across heterogeneous technologies. For
> example, you can unload data from a Microsoft SQL Server source using
> bcp and load this data into an Oracle staging area using SQL*Loader.
> The steps of LKMs that follow this strategy are often as follows:
>
> 1. Drop and create the loading table in the staging area
> 2. Unload the data from the source to a temporary flat file using either a source database unload utility (such as Microsoft SQL Server
>    bcp or DB2 unload) or the built-in OdiSqlUnload tool.
> 3. Generate the script required by the loading utility to load the temporary file to the loading table.
> 4. Execute the appropriate operating system command to start the load and check its return code.
> 5. Possibly analyze any log files produced by the utility for error handling.
> 6. Drop the loading table once the integration KM has terminated, and drop the temporary file.
>
> When using an unload/load strategy, data
> needs to be staged twice: once in the temporary file and a second time
> in the loading table, resulting in extra disk space usage and
> potential efficiency issues. A more efficient alternative would be to
> use pipelines between the "unload" and the "load" utility.
> Unfortunately, not all the operating systems support file-based
> pipelines (FIFOs).

If I understand above note correctly (points 2, 3, 4) a flow will look like:

```
Source table(Source Service) -> Flat file(Staging Area on Azure) -> Azure table(Staging Area on Azure)
```

I found **OdiSqlUnload** object, I try to unload data to file and I follow by:
http://odiexperts.com/calling-odisqlunload-using-odi-procedure-with-no-hardcoded-password/

My settings:
[image]
[image]

But it doesn't work. I receive an error:

```
Caused By: com.sunopsis.sql.SnpsMissingParametersException: ODI-30011: Parameter cannot be null:-DRIVER
```

Can you give me some advice how can I deal with it or similar works example?

Comment: Is your logical schema (POLIGON) connected to a physical schema through the context used at execution-time? If so, is the JDBC driver correctly set up in the Data Server (parent of the physical schema)? What is the code generated when you look at the task in the operator?

Comment: Thanks in advance for a reply. I left this method and use "Using Bulk Copy with the JDBC Driver" [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-bulk-copy-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017) in "Command on Target".